# Wix installer integration with text file

Tags: wix

I have an installation that copy files to the relevant location,install some of them in the GAC and install services.

I'm looking for a way to improve my installer and ease my application configuration by adding forms to the installer with some edit box which eventually will replace strings in my application configuration files, that way it will be more comfortable and user friendly to configure the application setting.

Is that possible?
if so, where should I look on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are asking, it looks like you would like to introduce some User Interface as part of your installation process. Wix has several inbuilt UI dialog sets that can help you do just this.

Take a look at the following:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/

Hope this helps.

If you would like to introduce a custom dialog in the user interface sequence, take a look at:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/a-single-dialog/

Try things out. These examples should be sufficient to help you get started.

Comment: I just can't find what I'm looking for. I want to add text boxes to the installation which the user will input data that i will take and update text file of my application. Is that possible?

Comment: Was this answered?  I am looking for the same thing.  I see that this is possible if the file is XML but mine is a properties file.